# How to find the sum of each Row in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Code Input:

```
3 3
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

How to find the sum of each Row.
This is the code for getting lists as input:

```
r, c = map (int, input().split())
lst = [] 
for _ in range(c): 
    arr=list (map (int, input().split())) 
    lst.append (arr[:r])?
```

Comment: `[sum(s) for s in lst]`, or, since you seem to be a fan of `map`, `map(sum, lst)`.

Comment: I want to get an output like:
Output :
Row 1 : 6
Row 2 : 15
Row 3 : 24

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below solution, you just have to add one line print(sum(arr)) as arr is a list, and sum(list) will give a summation of all the elements inside that list, or in case if in a list you just want to share a summation of all elements in a list then do : lst.append(sum(arr)).

```
r, c = map (int, input().split())
lst = [] 
for i in range(r): 
    arr = list (map (int, input().split()))
    lst.append(arr)

for i in range(len(lst)):
    print("Row {0} : {1}".format(i+1,sum(lst[i])))
```

Comment: I want to get an output like:
Output :
Row 1 : 6
Row 2 : 15
Row 3 : 24

Comment: @JohnJayakumar I have edited the code, please check it

Comment: @JohnJayakumar please check and suggest is this what you want with the edited solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the sum of each seperate row then this should work

```
x = """
3 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
"""

strings = [i for i in x.split("\n") if i] # find the rows
for i in strings:
    nums = sum([int(n) for n in i if n.isdigit()])
    print(nums)
```

Comment: I want to get an output like:
Output :
Row 1 : 6
Row 2 : 15
Row 3 : 24